# How can I run a.out file in visual studio code automatically?

Tags: build, visual-studio-code, g++

I try to edit tasks.json file like this

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "helloworld.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and the results are a.out.dSYM and a.out file. When I drag a.out to terminal, it runs successfully. but is there any way to run this automatically? without drag it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile and run with various ways.  Here's 3:

**1. Add a task to run your executable.**

Something like:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "helloworld.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "build and run hello world",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
            "dependsOn": "build hello world"
        }
    ]
}
```

**2. Using a Visual Studio Code extension:**

Such as:

[C/C++ Compile Run](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielpinto8zz6.c-cpp-compile-run)

After installing, there are several Command Palette options for "CompileRun" to compile/run with default/custom options, or you can use the F6/F7 shortcut.

Several other similar extensions do the same.  Search for "c/c++ run" in the Extensions Marketplace.

**3.  Old fashioned way:**

Simply open a new terminal in VS Code and run the executable the old-fashioned way ;-)

```
./a.out
```